# Drupal 7: Using Views to display articles with a taxonomy that is also selected for the current user

Tags: views, entities

I'm trying to make a View that displays all articles having the same value in an taxonomy field as the current user has in its taxonomy field (taxonomy is "Work Location" and I want to display the work location news)

For that I created the taxonomy and added several locations. Then I added a field based on this taxonomy to the user and to the article content type.

Now I'm trying to create the View but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Found my own solution:
See this link: http://blog.ampli.fi/filtering-a-drupal-7-view-based-on-a-user-profile-field/